# Button onClickListener dynamically

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I tried to write a code in order to make a simple calculator but the emulator didn't work !! it gave me this msg "*Sorry, the application Task_6 (process com.example.task_6 ) has stopped unexpectedly , please try again.*"

this is the msg from LogCat :
"at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native metod)" when I clicked on button (+) or backspace button :\\

the layout is something like windows cal :

this is my code and I wonder if there is a wrong with this code :\  !!

```
package com.example.task_6;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener   {

     EditText textBox;
     Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7;
     int number_1,number_2,result,temp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textBox= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TextBox);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
       }

    public void onClick(View arg) { 
    if(arg==b1){

        textBox.setText("");

    }

 if(arg==b2){   
     temp=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString().substring(0, textBox.length()-1));
     textBox.setText(temp); 
    }
 if(arg==b3){

    number_1=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
    textBox.setText("");
    number_2=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
    result=number_1+number_2;
 }

 if(arg==b4){

     number_1=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
     textBox.setText("");
     number_2=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
     result=number_1-number_2;  
 }

 if(arg==b5){
     textBox.setText(result);   
 }
 if(arg==b6){

     number_1=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
     textBox.setText("");
     number_2=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
     result=number_1*number_2;  
 }
 if(arg==b7){

     number_1=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
     textBox.setText("");
     number_2=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString());
     result=number_1/number_2;
      } 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
}
```

[image]

Comment: post your error log please ?

Comment: Read logcat message and if you can't solve the issue, post the error messsage

Comment: do you get the error when you click b5?

Comment: @blackbelt : No when I executed the code

Comment: @blackbelt  you are right that's one mistake. And also in on click i guess it should be `switch(arg.getId())
          {
           case R.id.button1 :
              //do something
           break;`

Comment: @Raghunandan check the id of the view is better but comparing the references should be work too

Comment: @Akari can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Akari that does not say anything about the crash. can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @Raghunandan : how can I get this I'm a beginner :\ !!

Comment: In your logcat output there's going to be more lines that say "at (something)" - we need all of those.

Comment: @Akari your image says you have more button which button is + button.

Comment: @thegrinner : this is the text of the only msg in catlog : "at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native metod)"

Comment: Is that the only line that has that? Usually a logcat will be rather long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with onclick statement

if you use:

```
public void function(View arg)
{
     ....
     ....
}
```

Then it should be called from the Layout XML itself.

XML file:

```
 <button
      android:id="@+id/b1"
      android:onclick="function" />
```

When you dynamically create the onClick function then it is like:

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(
 {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         ....
         ....
    }
 });
```

Comment: is there a problem with this peas of code :temp=Integer.parseInt(textBox.getText().toString().substring(0, textBox.length()-1));
      textBox.setText(temp);

Comment: because if enter 123 then press button backspace the value of edit text should be 12 and the emulator stopped when I press this button

Comment: if you dont enter any value? that is.. 

`String name="";`

`name.subString(0,-1);`

The program will crash..
this is one error.
Post your LogCat.. it will show the exact error